# How to freeze header of the page

Tags: html, css, header, freeze

My web template is based on div tags. I want to freeze header part (Header, logo etc), I mean when you scroll the page the header should be in fixed position.

```
 <!--Header and Logo -->
 <div id="outer">
 <div id="header">
   <h1><a href="#">Some Application</a></h1>
   <img src="/media/images/logo.gif"  height="95" width="190">
 </div>
```

Here is my css

```
#outer
{

}
/* Header */
#header
 {
height: 95px;
background-image: url();
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: bottom left;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Can some one help me? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the `position: fixed;` property. Here is an example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/austinbv/2KTFG/

Comment: What happens when content is wider than the screen and you x-scroll to see content? Does the header move with the content? Also, is there code to hide the header when the bottom of the content goes above the screen?

Answer (score 2):

You want [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The linked text is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A nifty CSS attribute:

```
#outer {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Freeze header at top (with correct header widths and alignment)

`position:fixed;` makes the header sit still but is far short of all the behavior I'd expect from a header - stick at the top of the screen when the actual table headers are scrolled up off the screen, and keep the widths and html of the frozen header synced with the actual table. This solution...

- declares a `function resizeHdr()` that will iterate through the `tblData` first row `<th>`'s and grab existing width and HTML
- sets global variables for the window and placeholder for how far down the screen the `tblData` top is
- on `$ready`, inserts a new, hidden shell table that at the top of the `<body>`
- sets the placeholder
- grabs width, margins from `tblData`
- calls `resizeHdr()` to populate the hidden cloned table
- sets a watcher for scrolling: y-scrolling shows the cloned header when the top of `tblData` (main table) passes the screen top and hides it again when the bottom of the table passes above the top of the screen; and x-axis scrolling moves the cloned header sideways because `position:fixed` is, well, fixed.
- sets a watcher for when the the window is resized to keep the widths of the cloned table in sync with `tblData`

```js
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load before freeze header -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var distance = 0, $window = $(window);
     function resizeHdr(){
         $("#tblDataHdr").css("width", $("#tblData").css("width"));
         var oTr=$("#tblDataHdrTr").html("");//short var for frozen header row
         $("#tblData tr").first().find("th").each(function(i){//loop through header to mimic
             oTr.append('<th style="width:'+$(this).css("width")+' !important">'+$(this).html()+'</th>');//copy content with forced width
         });
     }
     $(function(){
        $("body").prepend(// stuff frozen header table html into the page just inside/at top of <body>
            '<table class="'+$("#tblData").attr("class")+
            '" style="display:none;position:fixed;background-color:white;z-index:10;'+$("#tblData").attr("style")+
            '" id="tblDataHdr">'+
            '<tr id="tblDataHdrTr" class="" style=""></tr></table>'
        )
         distance=$('#tblData').offset().top;
         var oTr=$("#trHoldHdr");//stuff the frozen header
         $("#tblDataHdr").css({"margin-left":$("body").css("margin"),"margin-top":-parseInt($("body").css("margin"))+"px"});//position frozen hder
         $("#tblData tr:first").find("th").each(function(i){//populate <th>
             oTr.append("<th>"+$(this).html()+"</th>");
         });
         resizeHdr();
     });
     $(window).scroll(function(){
         $("#tblDataHdr").css("left", -$(this).scrollLeft());//frozen hdr pos fixed doesn't move w/ scrolling so this keeps it lined up (w/o "-" header slides twice as fast out to the right) 
         if($window.scrollTop() >= distance &&
         $window.scrollTop() <= distance + 1*$("#tblData").css("height").replace(/px/,"")){
             $("#tblDataHdr").css("display","");// Hdr has reached the top
         }else{
             $("#tblDataHdr").css("display","none");// Hdr below top
         }
     });
     $(window).resize(function(){
         resizeHdr();
     });
    </script>
    <body> 
   <table id="tblData"><thead>
    <tr><th><b style="color:red;">col 1</b></th><th><a href="#" title="hello world">Linked Wide Column Header</a></th><tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr><td>1234567890 1234567890 1234567890</td><td>xyz</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>.</td><td>.</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <div style="height:300px;">Below table</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I really like your approach, Gordon... but the code doesn't work...

Comment: What do you get? It sometimes misses the left margin of the table. I updated personal version of this to re-hide the freezeHdr when the bottom of the table scrolls above the top of the window. Also I have added variables to be able to do more than one on a page.

Comment: Appreciate the response... I'd really like to use this code; can't find it anywhere else. Maybe I'm not placing it in the page correctly? The effect that I'm getting is that it just does nothing. I'm not that familiar with JQuery...

Comment: Be sure jQuery is above this code or $(window) will break. Also there has to be a `<body>` tag for the $("body").prepend() to work.

Comment: Sho 'nuf, I copied/pasted and as you report - didn't work :/ So I jiggered around with it until now it should work if you copy/paste (note caveats above). I added code to hide the freezeHdr table when the bottom of the main table scrolls above the top of the window and replaced deprecated :first with .first()

Comment: @SteveGray thank you for letting me know of your trouble. I posted this solution last October after I got it working in my local code. I apologize that I didn't do the requisite self-check of the version I'd posted here after removing all the extra parameters from my local version. Plus jQuery had deprecated `:first`, now fixed in the edits I made. Cheers

Comment: Anyone tried this jQuery plugin? https://github.com/laertejjunior/freezeheader/find/master I have downloaded and will mess around with it to see if it handles one issue my version misses - that it doesn't pick up a left margin sometimes