# Why are these HTML column headers misaligned?

Tags: html, css, html-table

After much experimenting, I finally came up with fairly simple HTML that displays a
table the way I want:  6 columns with specific widths, with two columns
right-justified, scrolling under a
fixed header row.  However, the headers don't quite align to the columns:

[image: HTML table]

**How can I make the headers line up exactly with the data columns?**
My online searches have found this to be a common problem, but with no real
explanation of the cause or a known simple fix.

My HTML is below.  The columns widths are are magic
numbers because of the data
that will eventually be displayed.
Making the header text normal instead of bold,
or even empty headers,
has no effect on alignment.

If besides solving the alignment issue you also have a more simple way
of defining a table with the same features, please let me know.

**Edit:** `box-sizing: border-box;` as recommended by ProllyGeek seemed promising because it works on the sample data above,
but using different cell data still causes alignment to be slightly off
as shown here (the Price/Drops, Drops/Description, and Item#/Posted
column borders are off even when using `border-box`):

[image: retried with other data]

There are dozens if not hundreds of posts
wanting sticky headers over scrollable rows,
but apparently all solutions avoid dynamic columns,
often using color to hide the alignment issue,
or an enclosing div that has to know the table
width to show a scrollbar properly positioned alongside dynamic
column widths.  Most examples ignore column widths
and just use 100% wide tables with oversized columns.

**There appears to be no known automatic solution
for a sticky header, with dynamic column widths (no declared table width),
over scrollable rows, with precise header and column alignment,
using just pure CSS/HTML.**

I'm just going to hide misalignments using `thead { background-color: black; color: white; }`.

```html
<style>

table {
    width: 688px; /* 688 = column widths 80 + 56 + 280 + 120 + 56 + 96 */
    table-layout: fixed;
    font: 12px Courier;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 703px; /* 703 = 688 table width + 15 extra for scrollbar */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 65px;
}

thead tr { display: block; } 

tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #eee; }

th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) {text-align: right; width:  80px; }
th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2) {text-align: left;  width:  56px; }
th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {text-align: left;  width: 280px; }
th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) {text-align: left;  width: 120px; }
th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5) {text-align: right; width:  56px; }
th:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(6) {text-align: left;  width:  96px; }

</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Drops</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Item #</th>
      <th>Posted</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i wonder if its due to setting the width of `tbody`?

Comment: Which is a different width than you set the `table`.

Comment: He added an extra 15 px on purpose.

Comment: If table and tbody width are the same, alignment is worse, plus the scroll bar appears under the last column header instead of alongside the table.

Comment: Typically, I've seen 17px used for the scrollbar.

Comment: +1 more for the scrollbar overlaps tbody and the scrollbar so that the 2px edge becomes 1px; +2 more for the scrollbar makes tbody wider than the header.  In general, I've found that tweaking anything fails to fix the problem, and just introduces more discrepancies.

Comment: You need to forget about all of these custom style sizes and focus a strategy around [`#header { position: fixed }`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013686/how-to-freeze-header-of-the-page), or something more along these lines: https://algoart.fr/articles/css-table-fixed-header

Comment: Sorry, I can't avoid the custom widths because the application spec requires fixed columns widths with a mono font.  Like your article's fiddle examples, I've seen lots of one-color solid headers that hide the fact the header cell edges don't actually align with the data columns. Perhaps that's the only way to disguise the inability to do exact alignment.

Comment: An example of hiding the misalignment would be to add `thead { background-color: black; color: white; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution to your problem with fixed widths,
but a step toward your desire for

> a sticky header, with dynamic column widths (no declared table width),
> over scrollable rows, with precise header and column alignment, using
> just pure CSS/HTML.

I believe it's faster for large tables to be rendered with dynamic column widths,
**header/column alignment is then guaranteed**,
plus the code is no longer cluttered with magic numbers.
Adding scrolling requires using an enclosing `<div>` like the snippet below.

**UPDATE:** Per your comment request, here's a dynamic table (no declared column widths) with a scrolling div that automatically repositions the scrollbar as necessary.  Click the "Refill table" button to generate test tables.

```js
const SCROLLBARWIDTH = 16;

let maxWidth = 5; // initial max width of our dummy strings

function dummyString() {
  return 'x'.repeat(Math.floor((Math.random() * maxWidth)+1)); // dummy data that will tend to widen with each refill
}

function refill() {
  document.getElementById("theBody").innerHTML = '<tr></tr>'; // remove any previous table body
  let tableRef = document.getElementById("theTable"); // our scrollable HTML table that we'll add rows to
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) { // create 20 rows of dummy data
    let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1); // add a new row to the table, then set the 6 <td> cells...
    newRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(dummyString())); // price
    newRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(dummyString())); // drops
    newRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(dummyString())); // description
    newRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(dummyString())); // category
    newRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(dummyString())); // item #
    newRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(dummyString())); // posted
    }
  let tableWidth = window.getComputedStyle(tableRef).getPropertyValue('width'); // get resulting dynamic table width
  document.getElementById("container").style.width = parseInt(tableWidth) + 1 + SCROLLBARWIDTH + 'px'; // make scrolling div wide enough
  maxWidth++; // so our next refill will tend to have wider dummy strings
}

refill();
```

```css
#container { overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px; } /* width to be determined after table filled */

thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; }

table { font: 12px Courier; border-collapse: collapse; }

th { background: black; color: white; } /* hide scrolling behind the header */

table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<button onclick="refill()">Refill table</button> <!-- click to generate wider table -->

<div id="container">
<table id="theTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Drops</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Item #</th>
      <th>Posted</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="theBody">
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect alignment doesn't matter if the header has to be colored to hide the overlap. But if you can create pure js/css/html so the div scrollbar hugs a table that dynamically grows or shrinks column widths as the data changes, you can have the bounty.

Comment: It seems that with pure js/css/html you can have perfect column alignment with no scrolling, or scrolling with obliterating headers. Pick one. At least between your technique, and the original question's sample code, programmers have a choice of whether to used fixed widths or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using min, max-width instead of width.
Also, you added all the column width, but every column has a padding of 5px, which adds 5px on left and 5px on right. So, make sure you add them up.

Here is the fix:

```css
        table {
            /* width: 688px; 688 = column widths 80 + 56 + 280 + 120 + 56 + 96 + 60(padding)*/
            min-width: 748px;
            max-width: 763px;
            table-layout: fixed;
            font: 12px Courier;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        tbody {
            display: block;
            /* max-width: 763px; */
            /* 763 = 688 table width + 60(padding) + 15 extra for scrollbar */
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 65px;
        }

        thead tr {
            display: block;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        /* th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) {text-align: right; width:  80px; }
        th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2) {text-align: left;  width:  56px; }
        th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {text-align: left;  width: 280px; }
        th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) {text-align: left;  width: 120px; }
        th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5) {text-align: right; width:  56px; }
        th:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(6) {text-align: left;  width:  96px; } */

        th:nth-child(1),
        td:nth-child(1) {
            text-align: right;
            min-width: 80px;
            max-width: 80px;
        }

        th:nth-child(2),
        td:nth-child(2) {
            text-align: left;
            min-width: 56px;
            max-width: 56px;
        }

        th:nth-child(3),
        td:nth-child(3) {
            text-align: left;
            min-width: 280px;
            max-width: 280px;
        }

        th:nth-child(4),
        td:nth-child(4) {
            text-align: left;
            min-width: 120px;
            max-width: 120px;
        }

        th:nth-child(5),
        td:nth-child(5) {
            text-align: right;
            min-width: 56px;
            max-width: 56px;
        }

        th:nth-child(6),
        td:nth-child(6) {
            text-align: left;
            min-width: 96px;
            max-width: 96px;
        }

        .lastColumn {
            min-width: 114px !important;
        }
```

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Drops</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Item #</th>
                <th class="lastColumn">Posted</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>$5.00
                <td>Oct 10
                <td>Valuable item
                <td>Miscellaneous
                <td>1234
                <td>Sep 10 2020
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$5.00
                <td>Oct 10
                <td>Valuable item
                <td>Miscellaneous
                <td>1234
                <td>Sep 10 2020
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$5.00
                <td>Oct 10
                <td>Valuable item
                <td>Miscellaneous
                <td>1234
                <td>Sep 10 2020
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$5.00
                <td>Oct 10
                <td>Valuable item
                <td>Miscellaneous
                <td>1234
                <td>Sep 10 2020
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

You just need the last column to take the remaining width. So, specify to that column.

Comment: Believe it or not, this answer still suffers from misalignments like ProllyGeek's solution, when the rows don't contain repetitive data.  There's something about how tables are rendered that gets thrown off when scrolling is added. The only way headers and columns stay perfectly aligned seems to be when an enclosing scrolling div is used around a table with dynamic width columns, but then the table width changes and it's not clear how to make the scrollbar hug the table.

Comment: this solution seems most promising till the time I commented,  with variable length data its looks almost ok in mozilla, chrome, edge

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues: the scrollbar applied to tbody and the sizes that are not equal for table and tbody because of the borders.

**Instead, here is my proposal:**

I apply the scrollbar to the table, which I transform into a block to be able to set a `height` and an `overflow`. I make `thead` `sticky`. I remove all styles from `tbody` including fixed size.

```css
table {
  font: 12px Courier;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 772px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 65px;
}

thead {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* Required for the stickiness */
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
  width: 80px;
}
th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
  width: 56px;
}
th:nth-child(3),
td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: left;
  width: 280px;
}
th:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: left;
  width: 120px;
}
th:nth-child(5),
td:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: right;
  width: 56px;
}
th:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(6) {
  text-align: left;
  width: 96px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Drops</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Item #</th>
          <th>Posted</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>$5.00</td>
          <td>Oct 10</td>
          <td>Valuable item</td>
          <td>Miscellaneous</td>
          <td>1234</td>
          <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>$5.00</td>
          <td>Oct 10</td>
          <td>Valuable item</td>
          <td>Miscellaneous</td>
          <td>1234</td>
          <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>$5.00</td>
          <td>Oct 10</td>
          <td>Valuable item</td>
          <td>Miscellaneous</td>
          <td>1234</td>
          <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>$5.00</td>
          <td>Oct 10</td>
          <td>Valuable item</td>
          <td>Miscellaneous</td>
          <td>1234</td>
          <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit:**

For me it remains a problem of width:

- By accumulating the widths of the cells: 688px
- By accumulating the padding of the cells : 60px
- By accumulating the borders width (except the two outer ones): 10px
- By adding the width of the scroll bar: 14-18px
  By adding everything, we get 772-776px.

I no longer have this border problem by setting the width of the table to:

- 772px in Firefox,
- 772px seems to work too in Chromium/Brave... but I think it will depend on the size of the cell contents. 775px is safer since the size of the scrollbar looks slightly different.

If you need to keep 688px wide, you need to reduce the size of the cells (width or padding). Otherwise, you have to increase the width of the table.

I updated the code above.

Comment: This still doesn't work for different data in different rows.

Comment: On which browser? I hadn't noticed a problem with Firefox. In any case, I modified my answer. I think the problem is the miscalculated size. I also updated the code.

Comment: Note the vertical header separator between Category and Item # remains misaligned with the data cells when your snippet is run, so the problem remains.

Comment: On which browser? I see them aligned with Firefox 81 and Chromium 85 on Manjaro Linux. As I said, the scrollbar does not have the same size depending on the browser. For the snippet, I set the size to 772px; this may not be sufficient for the browser you are using. The other problem that may occur with a size that is too large (like 776px) is that the scrollbar is no longer stuck to the board with some browsers.

Comment: Misaligns for me with Firefox 81.0.1.

Comment: I switched to Windows to test. With Edge, I don't see any alignment issue. With Firefox, I see a slight gap in the alignment between Description & Category. By changing the width to 773px, the gap seems to disappear. Again, this is not ideal as each browser reacts differently ... But, keeping the original column sizes, a width between 773px and 775px should solve the problem. With 1 or 2px the separation between the table and the scrollbar is not really visible (for browsers with a smaller scrollbar).

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple just change:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

to

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Dayum, you get my upvote for being direct. A little explanation as to *why* this works would make your answer perfect.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work with other cell contents, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I got the borders to align by removing the `display:block` properties. But without the display property, you cannot set a height to a HTML table. The only workaround I could think of was to wrap the whole table in a div and assign a `max-height` property to the div.

I tried with a sticky header but the table body would scroll behind it and that does not look pretty. You can always block out the body content by adding  a background color to the table header th cells.

Maybe someone else might have a better solution to hiding the body content when scrolling.

```css
table {
            width: 688px;
            /* 688 = column widths 80 + 56 + 280 + 120 + 56 + 96 */
            table-layout: fixed;
            font: 12px Courier;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        tbody {
            /*display: block;*/
            width: 703px;
            /* 703 = 688 table width + 15 extra for scrollbar */
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 65px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        /*thead tr { display: block; } */

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        th:nth-child(1),
        td:nth-child(1) {
            text-align: right;
            width: 80px;
        }

        th:nth-child(2),
        td:nth-child(2) {
            text-align: left;
            width: 56px;
        }

        th:nth-child(3),
        td:nth-child(3) {
            text-align: left;
            width: 280px;
        }

        th:nth-child(4),
        td:nth-child(4) {
            text-align: left;
            width: 120px;
        }

        th:nth-child(5),
        td:nth-child(5) {
            text-align: right;
            width: 56px;
        }

        th:nth-child(6),
        td:nth-child(6) {
            text-align: left;
            width: 96px;
        }

        .tableContent {
            width: fit-content;
            border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
            max-height: 70px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        td {
            word-wrap: break-word
        }

        th {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: lightsteelblue;
        }
```

```html
<div class="tableContent">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Drops</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Item #</th>
                    <th>Posted</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable itemaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5.00</td>
                    <td>Oct 10</td>
                    <td>Valuable item</td>
                    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:**

Just noticed the part about the variable length data in the cells.
Modified my code

Comment: Hiding the misalignments by coloring the header has been used ever since `sticky` became available, but that can be done even without bothering with an enclosing `div`. As mentioned in the original post **Edit**, header color is the trick I've been resigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped `<td>` in `<tr>`. See [W3's docs](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/one-header/) for correct syntax.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  max-width: 763px;
  font: 12px Courier;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Drops</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th>Posted</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$5.00</td>
    <td>Oct 10</td>
    <td>Valuable item</td>
    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$5.00</td>
    <td>Oct 10</td>
    <td>Valuable item</td>
    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$5.00</td>
    <td>Oct 10</td>
    <td>Valuable item</td>
    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$5.00</td>
    <td>Oct 10</td>
    <td>Valuable item</td>
    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td>Sep 10 2020</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `</td>` was left out for brevity in the original post. Your answer doesn't address the misalignment issue when scrolling is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

So here's my take:

- Keep the table width specified
- Set `box-sizing: border-box` to both `td` and `th`
- Since table body is wrapped by `tbody` (which is set to `display: block` to enable overflow scrolling), apply the same `display: block` to `thead` (which wraps table headers). [Table elements has complex structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-internal) and the initial `display` value of `thead` is `table-header-group` so there might be some differences when calculating the width (that's my guess, would love to hear detail clarification from someone), so the idea here is to make `thead` to display as the same with `tbody`.

If you're using trackpad, this solution works fine, it preserves the alignment and the column width even with longer cell content. For the scrollbar appearing when you plug your mouse in, I think I will go with setting `display: none` to the scrollbar, it's a trade-off :/ (don't know any robust solution for that ugly scrollbar to not add up the width)

```html
<style>

table {
    width: 688px; /* 688 = column widths 80 + 56 + 280 + 120 + 56 + 96 */
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font: 12px Courier;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  /* width: 688px; */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 65px;
}

tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

thead { display: block; }

tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #eee; }

th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) {text-align: right; width:  80px; }
th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2) {text-align: left;  width:  56px; }
th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {text-align: left;  width: 280px; }
th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) {text-align: left;  width: 120px; }
th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5) {text-align: right; width:  56px; }
th:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(6) {text-align: left;  width:  96px; }

</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Drops</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Item #</th>
      <th>Posted</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item Valuable item Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to maintain the width of table header. Your design view broken because of border css. I have used "position:sticky" to Table header and gave a new div as parent of table and css is "overflow: auto;". Please have a look...

```css
.tableDiv {
height: 68px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: calc(688px + 15px);
}
table {
    width: 688px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font: 12px Courier;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 
}

tbody {
  width: 688px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #eee; }
```

```html
<div class="tableDiv">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Drops</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Item #</th>
      <th>Posted</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I added `box-sizing: border;` for all the tags `*` then set the `width` property for the first 3 child of `th` and `td` separately with different values.

Also, I removed the border from `table` so the `borders` of `th` and `td` doesn't add up & goes out of the box.

That's all I did in your current snippet, hope it would help.

```html
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
table {
    width: 688px; /* 688 = column widths 80 + 56 + 280 + 120 + 56 + 96 */
    table-layout: fixed;
    font: 12px Courier;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 703px; /* 703 = 688 table width + 15 extra for scrollbar */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 65px;
}

thead tr { display: block; }

tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #eee; }

th:nth-child(1) {text-align: right; width:  79px;}
th:nth-child(2) {text-align: left;  width:  56px;}
th:nth-child(3) {text-align: left;  width: 278px;}

td:nth-child(1) {text-align: right; width:  80px; }
td:nth-child(2) {text-align: left;  width:  56px; }
td:nth-child(3) {text-align: left;  width: 280px; }

th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) {text-align: left;  width: 120px; }
th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5) {text-align: right; width:  56px; }
th:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(6) {text-align: left;  width:  96px; }
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Drops</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Item #</th>
      <th>Posted</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5.00<td>Oct 10<td>Valuable item<td>Miscellaneous<td>1234<td>Sep 10 2020</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```